# How do I getLong() from the SharedPreference in a preference setting

Tags: android, xml, android-preferences

I have the following code to get long values from my xml preference file,

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()); 

long longBreak = Integer.parseInt(getPrefs.getString("breakTime", "8000"));
long shortBreak = Integer.parseInt(getPrefs.getString("breakTime", "5000"));
long workTime = Integer.parseInt(getPrefs.getString("workTime", "10000"));
```

For some reason my LogCat show's an error on the line for "SharedPreference getPrefs=...." and my android application breaks before it loads the long values....

I have my preference xml as follows,

```
<ListPreference
    android:entries="@array/workList"
    android:entryValues="@array/workTimes"
    android:key="workTime"
    android:summary="Choose Work Time"
    android:title="Work Time" />
<ListPreference
    android:entries="@array/breakList"
    android:entryValues="@array/breakTimes"
    android:key="breakTime"
    android:summary="Choose Break Time"
    android:title="Break Time" />
```

and my array values as follows,

```
<string-array name="workList">
    <item>25 Minutes</item>
    <item>10 Seconds</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="breakList">
    <item>15 Minutes</item>
    <item> 5 Minutes</item>
    <item>8 Secs</item>
    <item>5 Secs</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="workTimes">
    <item>1500000</item>
    <item>10000</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="breakTimes">
    <item>900000</item>
    <item>300000</item>
    <item>8000</item>
    <item>5000</item>
</string-array>
```

I have tested this same code in a diff app and it works fine.... any help? thanks in advance...

Comment: Please add your stacktrace. Also, to parse a long, you need to call `Long.parseLong()` instead of `Integer.parseInt()`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
 SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("file_pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
 to get a object of SharedPreferences
```

To get Long values from SharedPreferences: you should use putLong("key","value") from Editor of SharedPreferences class and getLong("key","default_value") to get values which you want. E.x:

//Creating:

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("file_pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit = shared.edit();
shared.putLong("key1","value1");
```

//Using:

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("file_pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
Long value_long = shared.getLong("key1",0);
//with 0 - default value
```

You can see this link to understand how to use SharedPreferences class to save simple information in Android clearly and easily:

[Save values before close the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127396/save-values-before-close-the-app/10127842#10127842)

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but with the what you have described how will the user see these entered settings in the preference screen? With the xml method the user can select which settings they want and I have some entered by default. I now want to read the values from the preference and use them in my activity. But for some reason my app breaks when it reaches the line SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());...

Comment: You can try this link: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html. It's so easy to understand.

Comment: @secretlm: in the linked article, the value is read using `getString()`. The OP wants to use `getLong()`.