# save the value of the array list to a spinner

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-spinner

I have a spinner in my app and I want to save the state of the array list to so if the user chooses an option and closed the app, I want the spinner to save it value if the user reopen my app.

My Main Activity:

```
        t1.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "andlso.ttf")
        val fonts = arrayOf("الخط الديواني", "الخط الأندلسي")

        spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fonts)
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object :AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

                val SelectedItem = parent!!.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

                val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("savefile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
                editor.putString("savefile", fonts.toString())
                editor.apply()

                if (SelectedItem == "الخط الديواني"){
                        t.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "andlso.ttf")
                }else if (SelectedItem == "الخط الأندلسي"){
                        t.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "frsspbl.TTF") 
                }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127396/save-values-before-close-the-app

Comment: I am a new learner of Kotlin and I don't know anything about java

Comment: The IDE has a java to kotlin code converter. So you can convert the code and check the answer.

Comment: I tried them and none of them works

Comment: use a `Preference` for that; this certainly works and is suitable for settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just write the following code in your mainActivity,

```
        val preferences = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val prefEditor = preferences.edit()

        val fonts = arrayOf("Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4")
        var adapterCountry = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fonts)

        val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
        spinner.adapter = adapterCountry;
        spinner.setSelection(preferences.getInt("position", 0))

        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                spinner.setSelection(position)
                prefEditor.putInt("position", position)
                prefEditor.apply()
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
            }
        }
```

this will do your work. I hope this is helpful for you.